# when we click on link the webview not show any content

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when we use this url ("https://premium.mysirg.com/learn/beginners-web-development") in webview the webview not show any content or when we click on link from website the page not loaded by webview and show blank white screen and when we load this url in browser it work fine and show all content but webView not show any content  how to solve this problem please help.

```
webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("https://premium.mysirg.com/learn/beginners-web-development");
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }

    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
});
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
});
```

Comment: did you check internet permissions

Comment: yes i am check internet permission

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is working for me. I will share the source code here for your use.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView webview;

String LoginUrl = "https://premium.mysirg.com/learn/beginners-web-development";


private static String TAG = "WebView";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
        /*@Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
 //                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.proceed();
        }*/
    });

    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        }
    });

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

//            webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla");
//        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1");
    
 
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(this));

    webview.loadUrl(LoginUrl);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //        super.onBackPressed();
    if(webview.canGoBack())
        webview.goBack();
    else
        finish();
}
}
```

Comment: thank you i am not add some setting that is why its not work